# Zebra printer query

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Are there any toolbox or cpcl commands that I can use to query some information from a zebra printer?

I'm looking for the following attributes
product.name, appl.version, apl.framework_version, and free space available

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SGDs to get that information.

e.g.

`! U1 getvar "appl.name"\r\n`

to get the firmware version.

Comment: Thanks! Any ideas on commands for "product name", and "available space"?

Comment: i think it's memory.flash_free or memory.ram_free (if you care about ram). And device.product_name